# Setting ImageBimap on imageButton from Uri stored in String Array

Tags: android

Code:
imagearray is Array of String.

```
          ParcelFileDescriptor fd;
         Uri imageUri2=Uri.parse(imagearray[1]);

        try {
            fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageUri2, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFileDescriptor());
          Bitmap resized2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp2, 100, 100, true);
           Bitmap conv_bm2 = ImageCropScale.getRoundedRectBitmap(resized2, 100);

          ib2.setImageBitmap(conv_bm2);
```

LogCat: of the application

```
try{ 07-15 17:58:26.121: I/Process(9506): Sending signal. PID: 9506 SIG: 9
07-15 17:59:52.062: D/AndroidRuntime(9905): Shutting down VM
07-15 17:59:52.062: W/dalvikvm(9905): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41664d40)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): Process: com.example.withimage, PID: 9905
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  

ComponentInfo{com.example.withimage/com.example.withimage.PictureChange}: java.lang.SecurityException:   

Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri    

content://media/external/images/media/4534 from pid=9905, uid=10103 requires  

android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/4534 from pid=9905, 
uid=10103 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:148)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:682)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1063)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:761)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:716)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
com.example.withimage.PictureChange.onCreate(PictureChange.java:82)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
07-15 17:59:52.069: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     ... 11 more
07-15 17:59:54.341: I/Process(9905): Sending signal. PID: 9905 SIG: 9
```

New LogCat: of the application
For some images it works well for other it just stopped working.

```
/*try(07-15 19:11:43.037: I/Adreno-EGL(24501): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: 
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8610_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
07-15 19:11:43.037: I/Adreno-EGL(24501): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
07-15 19:11:43.037: I/Adreno-EGL(24501): Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
07-15 19:11:43.037: I/Adreno-EGL(24501): Local Branch: 
07-15 19:11:43.037: I/Adreno-EGL(24501): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
07-15 19:11:43.037: I/Adreno-EGL(24501): Local Patches: NONE
07-15 19:11:43.037: I/Adreno-EGL(24501): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 
+ f2fd134 +  NOTHING
07-15 19:11:43.065: D/OpenGLRenderer(24501): Enabling debug mode 0
07-15 19:11:51.805: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 115K, 72% free 3180K/11120K, paused 12ms, total 13ms
07-15 19:11:51.843: I/dalvikvm-heap(24501): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.623MB for 15095824-byte allocation
07-15 19:11:52.014: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 31% free 17989K/25864K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
07-15 19:11:52.047: I/dalvikvm-heap(24501): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.084MB for 15095824-byte allocation
07-15 19:11:52.211: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 20% free 32810K/40608K, paused 12ms, total 14ms
07-15 19:11:52.287: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 36489K/40608K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
07-15 19:11:52.315: I/dalvikvm-heap(24501): Grow heap (frag case) to 52.150MB for 15095824-byte allocation
07-15 19:11:52.490: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 51310K/55352K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
07-15 19:11:52.520: I/dalvikvm-heap(24501): Grow heap (frag case) to 66.624MB for 15095824-byte allocation
07-15 19:11:52.687: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 66131K/70096K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
07-15 19:11:52.716: I/dalvikvm-heap(24501): Grow heap (frag case) to 81.097MB for 15095824-byte allocation
07-15 19:11:52.911: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 80952K/84840K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
07-15 19:11:52.911: I/dalvikvm-heap(24501): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 15095824-byte allocation
07-15 19:11:52.933: D/dalvikvm(24501): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 5% free 80942K/84840K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
07-15 19:11:52.933: E/dalvikvm-heap(24501): Out of memory on a 15095824-byte allocation.
07-15 19:11:52.933: I/dalvikvm(24501): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
07-15 19:11:52.933: I/dalvikvm(24501):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41665e40 self=0x41587520
07-15 19:11:52.934: I/dalvikvm(24501):   | sysTid=24501 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074438484
07-15 19:11:52.934: I/dalvikvm(24501):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=109 stm=17 core=0
07-15 19:11:52.934: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFileDescriptor(Native 
Method)
07-15 19:11:52.934: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:657)
07-15 19:11:52.934: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:689)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
com.example.withimage.PictureChange.onCreate(PictureChange.java:207)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
07-15 19:11:52.935: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 19:11:52.936: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 19:11:52.936: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-15 19:11:52.936: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 19:11:52.936: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 19:11:52.936: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-15 19:11:52.936: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-15 19:11:52.937: I/dalvikvm(24501):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 19:11:52.937: D/skia(24501): --- decoder->decode returned false
07-15 19:11:52.938: D/AndroidRuntime(24501): Shutting down VM
07-15 19:11:52.938: W/dalvikvm(24501): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41664d40)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501): Process: com.example.withimage, PID: 24501
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFileDescriptor(Native Method)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:657)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:689)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
com.example.withimage.PictureChange.onCreate(PictureChange.java:207)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-15 19:11:52.941: E/AndroidRuntime(24501):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*/)}
```

some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra
some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra
some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extra some lines are extrasome lines are extra
Thank you very much

Comment: Ok see the answers below.. :)

Comment: thank you... i have updated the logcat file. For some images it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this permission in your project's Androidmanifest file  just above the application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To write to external storage, you will indeed have to declare this in the manifest.See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html for learning in detail about the permissions and why they are required.

Comment: thank you... i have updated the logcat file. For some images it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.
Add **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```